# Why notepad++ plugins don't work in macro?

Tags: plugins, notepad++, macros

Why don't [Notepad++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad++) plugins work in a macro? For example:

```
Manual run plugin - Converter -> "ASCII -> HEX"
AAAA 4141414120
BBBB 42424242
CCCC 43434343

Runned as recorded macro
AAAA 4[nul][dc4][nul]Ő
Ąý
BBBB 4[nul][dc4][nul]Ő
Ąý
CCCC 4[nul][dc4][nul]Ő
Ąý
```

The same is with TextFx plugin, MathLab and so on... How can I solve this problem?

I need to automate (record macro) with EvaluateExpressions or other plugin methods (TextFx -> Convert -> Decimal To Hex) or (MyPlugin -> MyMethode).

Answer (score 3):

At least in version 5.9.2 of Notepad++, Settings-> Shortcut Mapper has a button for "Plugin commands."

You can assign a plugin command directly to any shortcut of your choice, without needing a macro or script.  "TextFx -> Convert -> Decimal To Hex" appears on line 144 as "C:Convert Decimal Number to Hex".

Or, add the plugin command to your right-click menu.  Use Settings-> Edit Popup ContextMenu.  Simpler than I expected!

Answer (score 2):

You could try to do it with the pythonscript plugin (you can get it with the plugin manager): http://sourceforge.net/projects/npppythonscript/

Once the plugin is installed create a new script and put :

```
notepad.runMenuCommand('TextFX Convert', 'Decimal To Hex')
```

docs: http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/docs/latest/notepad.html#Notepad.runMenuCommand

You can then add it to the pythonscript menu, and assign it a shortcut from the "shortcut mapper" window.

## Option 2

You can also try the more troublesome way by using the Universal macro patch, which is located over here:

http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3132767&group_id=95717&atid=612384

You would need to compile n++ though, and I'm not sure on how to do that.

Good luck.