# Notepad++ macro doesn't play back what I entered

Tags: notepad++, macros, unicode

This is my first Notepad++ (V7.8.4) macro. Something is going wrong.

The macro is supposed to insert a Unicode discretionary hyphen, U+00DA. The actions I recorded were: type 0, 0, d, a; hold down Shift and press LeftArrow four times, selecting the preceding four characters; run Plugins > Converter > Hex->ASCII. When I recorded the macro, Notepad++ inserted NUL xDA in the document (with View > Show Symbol > Show All Characters in effect), which is exactly what I wanted.

When I play the macro back, it inserts NUL NUL.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why notepad++ plugins don't work in macro?](https://superuser.com/questions/272281/why-notepad-plugins-dont-work-in-macro)

Answer (score 0):

Using Notepad++ plugins does not normally work in macros except when you use the tricks explained over at:

[Why notepad++ plugins don't work in macro?](https://superuser.com/questions/272281/why-notepad-plugins-dont-work-in-macro)